# importing model from TF model Zoo and training

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Referring this tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning , I created and trained a resnet model

```
preprocess_input = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input
IMG_SHAPE = IMG_SIZE + (3,)
base_model = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50(
                    include_top=False, weights='imagenet',input_shape=IMG_SHAPE, classes=2)
prediction_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
global_average_layer = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=IMG_SHAPE)
x = data_augmentation(inputs)
x = preprocess_input(x)
x = base_model(x)
x = global_average_layer(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
outputs = prediction_layer(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

So when I infer does the model perform data augmentation? I want the model to do data augmentation during training and not during inference

Also I get different result when i infer the images as batch and infer one image at a time. When i infer batch of image I always get accuracy 1 (this is an overfitted model), when I infer images one by one I get 2 - 4 errors (this number isn't constant, every time i get different accuracy)

This is my inference code

```
image_batch, label_batch = test_dataset.as_numpy_iterator().next()
class_list =['close','open']
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("shutter_model")
predictions = model.predict_on_batch(image_batch).flatten()

# Apply a sigmoid since our model returns logits
predictions = tf.nn.sigmoid(predictions)
predictions = tf.where(predictions < 0.5, 0, 1)

error = 0
for i in range(len(predictions)):
    if predictions[i]!= label_batch[i]:
        error+=1
print("number of errors when batch of images fed into the model: ",error)
        
print('=='*10)

error = 0
for i in range(len(image_batch)):
    img = tf.expand_dims(image_batch[i], axis=0)
    predictions = model(img)
    predictions = tf.nn.sigmoid(predictions)
    class_n = 1 if predictions[0][0] >0.5 else 0
    if label_batch[i]!= class_n:
        error+=1
print("number of errors when images fed into the model one by one: ",error)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
number of errors when batch of images fed into the model:  0
====================
number of errors when images fed into the model one by one:  3
```

My purpose was to train (either scratch or from pretrained weights) a 2 class model using Resnet50 architecture

Comment: In the above setup, augmentation would be applied on the training time, and in inference time, it will be not used.

Comment: when i evaluate the model with test dataset (loading batch of image) i get a accuracy of 1, but when i infer image one by one i get a accuracy of only 0.97, is this normal? @M.Innat

Comment: It seems not normal to get 1. Please add more info on this, possibly with reproducible code. I suggest running your model on mnist/cifar data set and try evaluation and inference (as you said) on its test set and update the results in your question.

Comment: This is a highly overfitted model, I  was just experimenting. What i wanted to ask is  that does global_average_layer affect the inference, does it give different output value when the input is fed in batches and not in batches @M.Innat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `model.predict(img)` when inference is done on one image instead of `model(img)`